# You have sent us an Illegal URL or an improperly formatted request. error in marketing cloud for <a> tag using AMP Script

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have added  tag link in email template link below, link working in preview and test while sending actual send not working.

```
<a href="%%=RedirectTo(@link)=%%" target="_blank">LastName</a>
```

link having below text

```
&utm_source=sfmc&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=Duplicate+Join&utm_term=%%%3dRedirectTo(%40url1)%3d%%&utm_id=24304&sfmc_id=23816084&campid=`
```

so i am getting below error.

```
Illegal Request
You have sent us an Illegal URL or an improperly formatted request.
```

If i removed utm text from url , link working as expected.

```
&utm_source=sfmc&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=Duplicate+Join&utm_term=%%%3dRedirectTo(%40url1)%3d%%&utm_id=24304&sfmc_id=23816084&campid=`
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: What do you mean by "automatically" when you say - "but automatically adding below text to link"? And main importantly, this string with UTM parameters does not look correct and probably it breaks the whole link.

Comment: Have you ensured that the variable `@link` is not empty in some of your sends? As an educated guess, that is what would appear to me as the issue as its adding the UTM tags on top of an empty var output which is why you see what you shared as the 'final link'.

Comment: @link is not empty one

Comment: if you delete the utm_term parameter form the URL does it work?

Comment: yes if i removed its working fine

Comment: then likely `&utm_term=%%%3dRedirectTo(%40url1)%3d%%` is where you are running into issues I am guessing.

Comment: Yes how to rmove &utm_term=%%%3dRedirectTo(%40url1)%3d%% from url?

Comment: @EazyE's answer solves your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is your utm_term parameter which appears to be the linkname personalization string.

If you add an alias to the <a tag such as:

`<a href="%%redirectto(@url1)%%" alias='CTALink'> Link Button </a>`

Would stop `%%%3dRedirectTo(%40url1)%3d%%` from being appended and now be `CTALINK`

Comment: Thank you its working